# Banner Picker in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if my current jQuery code could be improved? If yes, can you give me improvements?

```
$(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#bannerPickerToggleIcon").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bannerPicker").slideToggle();
        $("this").css({"display": "block"});
        $("#bannerPickerToggleIcon").toggleClass("active");
    });
    $("#bannerPicker span").click(function()
    {
        var bannerid = $(this).attr("id");
        $.cookie('bannerimg', bannerid,
        {
            expires: 365,
            path: '/'
        });
        $("body").removeClass().addClass(bannerid);
    });
    if (($.cookie('bannerimg') !== null))
    {
        $("body").addClass($.cookie('bannerimg'));
    }
    else
    {
        $("body").addClass("bannerDefaultImage");
    }
});
</script>
```

The code allows to open a selection of banners allowing the user to select a banner from the selection. Once a user has selected a banner, this one is saved via a cookie to save the selection. I created a [cookie js file](http://prntscr.com/7mcehx). It's the default cookie file from jQuery. Currently the code works, but I would like to know if it could be improved.

Comment: `$("this").css({"display": "block"});` <-- Do you mean `$(this).css({"display": "block"});`? (no quotes around `this`)

Comment: `if` block could be: `$("body").addClass($.cookie('bannerimg') ? $.cookie('bannerimg') : "bannerDefaultImage");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your JQuery code in `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. See this Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/is-document-ready-necessary) for more details on that.

The general style for brackets is that the open bracket is on the same line of the declaration, like this below example.

```
function f() {
    ...
}
```

Other than that, there's not much else here that I can see that's glaringly wrong, or in need of review. If there's anything else that you want me to cover, just ask, and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW (changes are in the comments):

```
/*
    Removed (presumably) superfluous .ready() and wrapped in SEAF.
*/
(function($) { // $ mapped to jQuery

    // Store body so you don't have to do the lookup twice (performance)
    var $body = $('body');

    /* 
        Use .on() instead of .click().
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click
    */
    $('#bannerPickerToggleIcon').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Fixed typo (removed quotes around this)
        $(this).css('display', 'block');

        // Reorganized for clarity
        $('#bannerPicker').slideToggle();
        $('#bannerPickerToggleIcon').toggleClass('active');
    });

    // Use .on() instead of .click().
    $('#bannerPicker span').on('click', function() {
        var bannerid = $(this).attr('id');

        $.cookie('bannerimg', bannerid, {
            expires: 365,
            path: '/'
        });

        // Use stored reference to body
        $body.removeClass().addClass(bannerid);
    });

    /*
        Use stored reference to body and convert if block to tertiary.
    */
    $body.addClass(
       $.cookie('bannerimg') ? $.cookie('bannerimg') : 'bannerDefaultImage'
    );

// Pass in jQuery to SEAF
}(jQuery));
```